# show confirm dialog when i click in a FormatImage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

i have a column in my sjg grid and i format it with function formatImage(),now i want to show confirm message when the image is clicked.

these is my format image function

```
function formatImage(cellvalue, options, row) {
    return "<img src='"+ context_path +"/images/page_edit.png' onClick='$.publish("+"&apos;edit_eleve&apos;, {old_name:" +"&apos;"+cellvalue+"&apos;"+ "})' />";

}
```

thanks

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="eleveId"
                    title="Supprimer" 
                    editable="false" 
                    sortable="false"
                    align="center"

                    formatter="formatImage"
                    onclick="$.publish('edit_eleve');"

    />
```

and

```
$(document).ready( function() {  
    $.subscribe('edit_eleve', function(event, data) { 

            editEleve(data.old_name);


        return false;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm()
{
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed?'))
      // do something
    else
      // do something else
}
</script>

<img src="#" onclick="confirm()" />
```

Comment: thanks but how to add confirm to onclick="confirm()" because there is another function called before onClick='$.publish("+"&apos;edit_eleve&apos;, {old_name:" +"&apos;"+cellvalue+"&apos;"+ "})'

Comment: Just add semicomma then confirm() like so:
    onClick='$.publish("+"&apos;edit_eleve&apos;, {old_name:" +"&apos;"+cellvalue+"&apos;"+ "});confirm()'

Answer (score 1):

Please show where you call formatImage?

You can wrap the call of this function, or the body of the function in the following

`if (confirm('Whats up?')) { //do };`

Comment: i edited my post, by the way javascript create for me another popup dialog when i click on it.

Comment: Check out the usage of confirm here. http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php